# I would like put a optional "wrong number. Try again" when is

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, do-loops

I have just started learn java codes, that is why might I have a simple question that is not simple for me.

I would like put a optional "wrong number. Try again" when is entered different number than secretNum. May you guys help me out on this code?

// I need learn how put "try again" when the number is != than guess number.

```
    /* I have tried
     * 1)Change the signal "==" or "!=".
     * 2) do {
        System.out.println("Guess what is the number 0 to 10: ");
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            guess = sc.nextInt();
        }
    } while(secretNum != guess);{
    System.out.println("Well done");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Are you ready for the next step?");
    System.out.println();
    }
     */
```

`````````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String userName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello " + userName + ",");
            System.out.println();
        }

        int secretNum = 5;
        int secretNum2 = 15;
        int guess = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Guess what is the number 0 to 10: ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                guess = sc.nextInt();
            }
        } while(secretNum != guess);{
        System.out.println("Well done\n");
        System.out.println("Are you ready for the next step?\n");
        } 


        // I need learn how put "try again" when the number is != than guess number. 

        /* I have tried
         * 1)Change the signal "==" or "!=".
         * 2) do {
            System.out.println("Guess what is the number 0 to 10: ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                guess = sc.nextInt();
            }
        } while(secretNum != guess);{
        System.out.println("Well done");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Are you ready for the next step?");
        System.out.println();
        }
         */


        System.out.println("Enter Yes or No");
 while(!sc.next().equals("yes")&& !sc.next().equals("no"));{
    System.out.print("Yes");    
        }

        do {
        System.out.println("Guess what is the number 11 to 20: ");
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            guess = sc.nextInt ();
        }
        }while(secretNum2 != guess);{
        System.out.println("Congratulations");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The End");
        }
        }
        }
````````
`````````

Comment: HINT: an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `do{} while()` for the checks you want to do here, just `while(){}` loops would be enough.

Please try this code instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String userName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello " + userName + ",");
            System.out.println();
        }

        int secretNum = 5;
        int secretNum2 = 15;
        int guess = 0;

        System.out.println("Guess what is the number 0 to 10: ");

        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            guess = sc.nextInt();
        }

        while (secretNum != guess) {
            System.out.println("Please try again\n");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                guess = sc.nextInt();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Well done\n");
        System.out.println("Are you ready for the next step?\n");

        System.out.println("Enter Yes or No");
        while (!sc.next().equals("yes") && !sc.next().equals("no"))
        {
            System.out.print("Yes");
        }

        System.out.println("Guess what is the number 11 to 20: ");

        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            guess = sc.nextInt();
        }

        while (secretNum2 != guess) {
            System.out.println("Please try again\n");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                guess = sc.nextInt();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Congratulations");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The End");

    }
}
```

Comment: I think the do-while loops were a better choice; they're more concise and exist for this type of situation.  Also there are still a few problems with the line `while (!sc.next().equals("yes") && !sc.next().equals("no"))`. Though, that's not the section he was asking about, I'll leave the statement for the OP.

Comment: Yes, do-while loops would work too I just said you don't need it in this situation, about the `while (!sc.next().equals("yes") && !sc.next().equals("no"))` piece of code is not in the scope of his question, that is why I didn't treat it...

Comment: @AdrianoMarra thank you for you response.It's worked. It's helped me a lot. I don't know much about code, yet. So, I still have basic questions.

Comment: @EdgarSousa you're welcome and keep it up, there are no basic questions everyone started somewhere... Happy coding man! :)